# How to move Entries from DataBase A to B?

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a Database called FooBar, and another one, that is from the Same style, called FooBarTrash.

```
FooBar:
Tables: User|Something|Foo|Bar

FooBarTrash:
Tables: User|Something|Foo|Bar
```

So I want to move one entry from `FooBar.User` to `FooBarTrash.User`.
Is there an MySQL Command to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mysql and your database user has access to both databases you can try something like this

```
insert into FooBarTrash.User select * from FooBar.User;
```